# How to change pseudo-class state of table column?

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I'm trying to style the following calendar so that the `TableColumn` headers are pink when the day they belong to is not part of the current month (i.e. March 26th - March 31st and May 1st - May 29th):

[image]

I extended `TableView` like this:

```
public class DayTableView extends TableView<Appointment> {

private static PseudoClass OFF_MONTH_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("off-month");

public DayTableView() {
    getStyleClass().add("day-table-view");
}

private BooleanProperty offMonth = new BooleanPropertyBase(false) {

    public void invalidated() {
        pseudoClassStateChanged(OFF_MONTH_PSEUDO_CLASS, get());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "off-month";
    }
};

public void setOffMonth(boolean b) {
    offMonth.set(b);
}
```

}

And added this styling:

```
.day-table-view  {
-fx-font-size: 9 px;
-fx-background-color: lightcyan;
```

}

```
.day-table-view:off-month {
-fx-font-size: 9 px;
-fx-background-color: pink;
```

}

But this was the result:

[image]

So I tried styling like this:

```
.day-table-view .table-column  {
-fx-font-size: 9 px;
-fx-background-color: lightcyan;
```

}

```
.day-table-view .table-column:off-month {
-fx-font-size: 9 px;
-fx-background-color: pink;
```

}

But the `TableColumn`s only formatted in light cyan (It looks just like the first calendar image.

So I tried this styling:

```
.day-table-view .table-column  {
-fx-font-size: 9 px;
-fx-background-color: lightcyan;
```

}

```
.day-table-view:off-month .table-column {
-fx-font-size: 9 px;
-fx-background-color: pink;
```

}

And it worked, except that I only want the `TableColumn` *headers* to change color, not the backgrounds of the `TableColumn`s:

[image]

So I tried extending `TableColumn` instead:

[image]

But as you can see there is no `pseudoClassStateChanged` method. So I was wondering what exactly I need to do to make just the `TableColumn` headers change?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `lookup`?

```
tableView.applyCss();
tableView.layout();
PseudoClass pseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("off-month");
tableView.lookupAll(".column-header").forEach(node -> {
    node.pseudoClassStateChanged(pseudoClass, true);
});
```

---

```
.table-view .column-header:off-month {
    -fx-background-color: pink;
}
```

[image]